# Center a UIImageView over a MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view that contains both a `MKMapView` and an `UIImageView`. The MKMapView is positioned via constraints set on its auto-alignment. For the image view, I would like to programmatically position the center of the image over the center of the image view. Here is what I've tried:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var centerPinImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centerPinImageView.bounds = mapView.bounds
        centerPinImageView.center = mapView.center
        centerPinImageView.frame = mapView.frame
        centerPinImageView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

This code does not change the position of the image view. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try same code in below method instead of viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

}
```

OR

Add this line for image view,

```
centerPinImageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
```

Hope it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a XIB file why don't you just make sure the MapView and ImageView are siblings and then set centre constraints for the ImageView to match those of the MapView?

Comment: ctrl+drag from the image to the map view.